# How to increase heap size in solr or tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, solr

When i run the command below:
127.0.0.1:8080/solr/suggest?spellcheck.build=true
I got an exception as below, anyone knows how to increase heap size in tomcat or solr?

Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 - Error report

## HTTP Status 500 - Java heap space

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

**type** Status report

**message** Java heap space

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

**description** The server encountered an internal error (Java heap space

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

#### Apache Tomcat/7.0.27

%

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find the command that you use to start the server that runs Solr (Tomcat or Jetty) and add java heap size options to it - e.g. -Xmx500m will set a max heap size of 500 MB, and -Xms300m will set an initial heap size of 300 MB.

For Tomcat, find catalina.sh, open it up and find the line that sets CATALINA_OPTS. Add the options for -Xms and -Xmx to that line. In Windows you don't put them in quotes, and in Linux you do.

Comment: what is the exactly value i should append to CATALINA_OPTS? currently i found it looks like <pre>CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS $JPDA_OPTS"</pre> can you please show me the exact modification to this? and what's the max value i can set in a unix-like os(Mac)? thanks a lot! i am new to this solr and tomcat thing...so that i have to ask for an exact solution while i am still searching online. thanks!!

Comment: CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS $JPDA_OPTS -Xms1g -Xmx2g" - something like that will set an initial size of 1 gigabyte and a max size of 2 GB. The max value you can set depends on how much memory you have and whether your OS is 64-bit or not.

Comment: thanks a lot!! :) should i add these values to CATALINA_OPTS or JAVA_OPTS, or either one will work? again, thanks a lot for helping me in the evening~ my machine is a 64bit mac :)

Comment: I think either one will work. You're welcome. You can set the memory values to as high as you like considering how much memory you have on the machine.

Comment: great! Let me try 1g, 2g now :), i have a max of 4g only...hope it's not running out of memory again :))) have a nice evening! and thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: why i am the only one asked this question? i even came back to check the answer again today :))))

Comment: Hey guys, Can you please let me know where I find this Catalina.sh file i Tomcat8

Answer (score 0):

Found the exact answer on web, changes made to JAVA_OPTS. append "-Xms256m -Xmx512m" in the section below, in catalina.sh

```
if [ -z "$LOGGING_MANAGER" ]; then
   JAVA_OPTS ="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms256m -Xmx512m"
else 
  JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $LOGGING_MANAGER -Xms256m -Xmx512m"
fi
```

Anyway, still running out of heap size...how big i can set this?